# If we change a primary key value, why don't we have to change a dependent column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

I watched [one tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrYLYV7WSHM&t=609s) about database normalization.

The table looks like this:

```
|Item(PK) | Supplier | Supplier Phone | Price|
---------------------------------------------
| Xbox One| Microsoft| 1234           | 250  |
---------------------------------------------
| PS4     | Sony     | 4321           | 300  |
---------------------------------------------
| PS Vista| Sony     | 4321           | 400  | 
---------------------------------------------
```

According to the tutorial this table is in 2NF and every column depends on the PK.

What I don't understand is how column Supplier depends on the PK and has the same value for different rows. If the logic is that B (supplier) depends on A (PK), and we change A, should B be changed? Why in this case would the Supplier for the changed PK remain the same?

Comment: In 3NF you would split the table up to remove duplicates of supplier. Right now, in 2NF you're only making sure everything depends on the key. So as of 2NF it's correct, but not yet in 3NF

Comment: Hi. Does "and we change A" mean "and we look at a different row", or "and we change an A value to get a different table"? You are not clear. Please use longer sentences & refer clearly to things. Don't try cram things into phrases or sentences or use generic words. That might give a vague description consistent with what you mean but it doesn't *unambiguously explain what you mean*. This also happens a lot in your comments. No wonder they go on & on. Please edit question to be clear. (Don't put clarifications into comments.)

Comment: @Moseleyi "Phone clearly doesn't depend on PK" is a contradiction--a PK, as a CK, is a set of attributes that determines all others. That's the same misconception/misinterpretation of "depends" that NikolasBozic has.

Comment: I just listened to some of that video, it's nonsense, they are suffering from the same misconceptions about "depends", and they don't know what they are talking about. Find an online college/university course, eg at stanford.edu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Item/A being PK (primary key) implies that there's only one Supplier/B value per Item/A value. It doesn't say that there's only one value per table.

That video is nonsense. They are suffering from the same misconceptions about "depends" & FDs (functional dependencies) & PKs as your question (so maybe that's where you got them from) and many other misconceptions and they don't know what they are talking about. Find an college/university textbook, slides and/or course (of which many are free online).

---

We can talk about the FDs, superkeys, unique column sets, CKs (candidate keys) & PK of a table *value* or a table *variable*. A table variable has an instance of one of those things if every table value that can arise in the given business/application has it as an instance.

> What I don't understand is how column Supplier depends on PK and has the same value for different rows.

A column set is functionally dependent on another when the determined set can only have one value per given value of the determining set.

But that doesn't imply that different determining values have different determined values.

A superkey is a set of columns that has a different subrow value in every row. A CK is superkey containing no smaller superkey. A PK is some CK that you chose to be PK. *Every* column set functionally depends on every superkey. Some of which are CKs. One of which can be PK.

But that doesn't imply that some subrow *other* than a superkey/CK/PK (and *every* subrow *must* be functionally dependent on them by definition) is unique.

> If the logic is that B (supplier) depends on A (PK), and we change A, should B be changed?

Not on the basis of A being PK/CK. A being PK/CK implies that A and every superset of A is unique. If you "change A" in the sense of looking at a different row or looking at a different table value that has a different A value for that row (which can't be in any other row of either table), that doesn't restrict what B can be.

Some *other* constraint might restrict what B can be. Eg if the FD {Supplier} -> {Supplier Phone} holds then that restricts what Supplier Phone can be in other rows even though Item being PK does not.

Whether any particular FD holds depends on what rows are supposed to go into a table in a given situation & what situations can arise. Then what FDs hold determines what the superkeys & CKs are. Then you can pick a CK as PK.

Comment: Can you explain this please:  "A superkey is a unique column set. A CK (candidate key) is superkey containing not smaller superkey. A PK (primary key) is some CK (candidate key) that you chose to be PK" Whas is superkey in this example ?

Comment: (updated/corrected) I edited my answer to correct & clarify the quote & add that there are separate versions of these terms for *values* & *variables*. Which did you mean? The superkeys of that table as a value are {Item}, {Price} & every superset of those. I don't know all the superkeys of that table as a variable because you didn't give enough info. (Re NFs, CKs, superkeys and/or FDs.) (You don't even give enough info to justify 2NF.) This is all absolutely basic, read some academic textbook chapter(s) on normalization then memorize & use the definitions. PS Please act on my other comments.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion might have arisen from the misunderstanding that the phone number belongs to a customer, where in reality it is a Supplier Number.

In this case if you have a product X, you know it has to come from supplier Y, and that supplier an only have 1 phone number Z. It shows you that Z is directly dependent on X. If you have an XboX the phone number will be 1234, if you have a PS4 it will be 4321.

Of course item doesn't depend on the phone, because you can have many items for the same phone but that's for a different step in normalisation.

So ideally we would have supplier table with name + phone, and in product table only reference to supplier_id

Comment: Ok but dependency between item and Suplier, how 2 different items can have same supplier in 2nf?

Comment: I just told you because it's okay in 2NF, supplier depends on the item and that is all that 2NF stands for, everything has to depend on the key - regardless if you have 50 items with the same supplier or only one. in 3NF you remove those duplicates by splitting the tables

Comment: Ok can you explain if B depends on A, we change A, B remain same? This is what nuke my brain:)

Comment: Can column depend on pk and on other column at the sam time?

Comment: Yes in this case it can, because at this moment we still have information about the Product and Supplier in one table. Imagine if it had 10 columns about the product and 10 about supplier.. In 2NF all supplier columns would be dependent on the product,, for example supplier's address, or phone - it is dependent on supplier's name which is dependent on the product.Then we split them up and it will be in 3NF

Comment: Ok. but here, what else Suplier depends, beside item?

Comment: Supplier depends on item and Supplier Phone, because for particular Supplier you have a particular Phone and vice versa. So Supplier Phone depends on Supplier and Item, Supplier depends on Supplier Phone and Item, Price depends on Item. All three somehow depend on the PK

Comment: Ok, but imagine we dont have suplier phone column. What would then suplier depend beside pk?

Comment: Nothing, and that's okay, 2NF means columns have to depend on PK, nothing "extra" is necessary

Comment: but how if coulumn depend only on pk needs more normalisation then. we changed pk , suplier didnt change?

Comment: What you want to say if coulmn depends only on pk is not in 3nf?

Comment: No no, let's focus on 2N: "All attributes that are not part of the primary key are functionally dependent on the primary key". 3NF says that it can ONLY depend on the key, in this case "Phone" will not be correct

Comment: and its possible that atribute remain same when we change primary key

Comment: After any changes to the keys you have to re-evaluate your structure and all the attributes

Comment: Re "confusion might have arisen from the misunderstanding that...' The PK would still determining every column. It might stop {Item} from *being* a PK/CK in *similar* circumstances *but here we know that it is one*. Re "It shows you that Z is directly dependent on X": It shows Z is (informally) *in*directly dependent on X. Maybe you mean *transitively* but that's if *also* Y doesn't determine X. Re "supplier depends on the item and that is all that 2NF stands for, everything has to depend on the key": That's so vague it's useless & misleading. Etc. I hope you'll reduce wrong & unclear claims.